# Alarmmanager doesn't broadcast, or broadcast receiver fails to receive the broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have created a method which it is called by pressing a save button under my main activity as follows:

```
public  void scheduleAlarms(Context ctxt) {
        String [] calvalue = (MessageDelay.getSelectedItem().toString()).split(" ",   3);
        int H = Integer.parseInt(calvalue[1]);
        Log.v("Timer","Timer"+H);

        switch (H){

        case 9:
                H=9;
                break;
        case 12:
                H=12;
                break;

        case 3: 
                H=15;
                break;
        case 5: 
                H=17;
                break;
        case 6: 
                H=18;
                break;
        case 8: 
                H=20;
                break;

        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, H);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

          AlarmManager mgr=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
          PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

          mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
          Log.v("Timer","Timer");
        }
```

And then I have added a line to manifest as follows :

```
<receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
```

And then created a receiver class as follows:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Set up new intent
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, SendMessage.class);

            // Start new intent
            context.startService(newIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I test it on emulator I cannot receive any broadcast :(

could anyone please advice me what I am doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `PendingIntent` for a service, but expect to receive a broadcast. Try using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

Comment: Dude you are Genius , it worked. I can't believe what a silly mistake I made there. Thanks a lot :)